# How to generate random string with no duplicates in java

Tags: java, string, random

I read some answers , usually they use a set or some other data structure to ensure there is no duplicates. but for my situation , I already stored a lot random string in database , I have to make sure that the generated random string should not existed in database .

and I don't think retrieve all random string from database into a set and then generated the random string is a good idea...

I found that System.currentTimeMillis() will generate a "random" number , but how to translate that number to a random string is a question...I need a string with length 8.

any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: sure you can append 7 digit random number to some letter to make it 8 digit random string.And `System.currentTimeMillis` does not generate random number. it just gives you current time in millis from January 1, 1970 UTC

Comment: First of all, `currentTimeMillis` isn't even remotely random... I think your premise is basically flawed, but you only need to generate a random string and check for existence against the DB, which is a lot more light weight than reading the DB into a set.

Have a look at [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)'s - they might work for you.

Comment: You don't need to retrieve all the strings from DB, use UNIQUE constraint on your random strings column. It will fail inserting any duplicate string this way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Apache library** for this: [RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html)

```
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8).toUpperCase() // for alphanumeric

RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8).toUpperCase() // for pure alphabets
```

> randomAlphabetic(int count)
>             Creates a random string whose length is the number of characters specified.
>
> randomAlphanumeric(int count)
>             Creates a random string whose length is the number of characters specified.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two issues here - creating the random string, and making sure there's no duplicate already in the db.
   If you are not bound to 8 characters, you can use a UUID as the commenter above suggested.  The UUID class returns a strong that is highly statistically unlikely to be a duplicate of a previously generated UUID so you can use it for this precise purpose without checking if its already in your database.

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Or if you don't care whether what the unique id is as long as its unique you could use an identity or autoincrement field which pretty much all DB's support.  If you do that, though you have the read the record after you commit it to get the identity assigned by the db.

which produces a string which looks something that looks like this:

```
5e0013fd-3ed4-41b4-b05d-0cdf4324bb19
```

If you are have to have an 8 character string as your unique id and you don't want to import the apache library, \you can generate random 8 character string like this:

```
final String alpha="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
final Random rand= new Random();

public String myUID() {
    int i = 8;
    String uid="";
    while (i-- > 0) {
        uid+=alpha.charAt(rand.nextInt(26));
    }
    return uid;
}
```

To make sure its not a duplicate, you should add a unique index to the column in the db which contains it.
You can either query the db first to make sure that no row has that id before you insert the row, or catch the exception and retry if you've generated a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Method `currentTimeMillis()` returns the current time in milliseconds in long so convert long to string, and `s.substring(5, s.length())` give you last 8 digit's of milliseconds those are always identical for each millisecond.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println(s.substring(5, s.length()));
}
```

You have to make sure that this string is available or not in your database each time.

Comment: ...and this has length 8? Why aren't you using `s`?

Comment: And what happens when `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns more than 13 digits?